# Use if else conditions with shortcuts

Tags: c#

Below is my codes:

Code 1:

```
int x = 10;

if (x < 10)
{
    if (x < 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("less than 5");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("value is between 5 and 10");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("grater than 10");
}
```

Code 2:

```
int x = 10;

if (x > 5 && x < 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value is between 5 and 10");
}
else if (x < 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("less than 5");
}                
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("grater than 10");
}
```

How can I write this code using inline if conditions.

Comment: Just FYI, the original logic is already completely wrong.  With x = 10, both Code 1 and Code 2 will say "grater than 10"!  Also, if x = 5, Code 2 will say "grater than 10"!  I'll give an answer that assumes these problems are intentional...

Comment: hi I just want to know the basic difference between  write inline if condition for nested if and if else if conditions. So I have given just simple example of both. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there are multiple problems with your original code, here is your code using inline ifs:

I've added code with parenthesis for clarity.

Code 1:

```
int x = 10;
MessageBox.Show(
    (x < 10) ?
    (
        (x < 5) ?
        (
            "less than 5"
        )
        :
        (
            "value is between 5 and 10"
        )
    )
    :
    (
        "grater than 10"
    )
);
```

In one line:

```
int x = 10;
MessageBox.Show( (x < 10) ? ( (x < 5) ? "less than 5" : "value is between 5 and 10" ) : "grater than 10" );
```

Code 2:

```
int x = 10;
MessageBox.Show(
    (x > 5 && x < 10) ?
    (
        "Value is between 5 and 10"
    )
    : 
    (
        (x < 5) ?
        (
            "less than 5"
        )                
        :
        (
            "grater than 10"
        )
    )
);
```

In one line:

```
int x = 10;
MessageBox.Show( (x > 5 && x < 10) ? "Value is between 5 and 10" : ( (x < 5) ? "less than 5" : "grater than 10" ) );
```

Comment: This is wrong, this code won't actually compile. You can't use the ternary operator expression as a statement.

Comment: Good point.  I've adjusted my answer.  It now mostly matches El Ronnoco's.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x=10;

MessageBox.Show( 
  x < 10 ? ( x < 5 ? "less than 5" : "between 5 and 10" ) : "greater than 10" 
);
```

Although I would advise against complex ternary statements - they can become very confusing.

Note also that `greater than 10` should really be `greater than or equal to 10`...

Answer (score 0):

See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

`String message = (x > 10 ? "Greater than 10" : (x < 5 ? "Less than 5" : "Value is between 5 and 10"))`

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ternairy operator: `var = <condition> ? <value-if-true> : <value-if-false>`

You can reform your code as follows:

```
int x = 10;
MessageBox.Show(x < 10 ? (x < 5 ? "less than 5" : "value is between 5 and 10") : "grater than 10")
```

The brackets are best for keeping it readable, but superfluous. Even better for keeping things readable is using this only on very short expression.